# VimClojure and Clojure 1.2

Tags: vim, clojure

What's the latest for using VimClojure with Clojure 1.2?

I've tried the instructions from a number of [different](http://lisp4fun.blogspot.com/2010/02/leiningen-and-vimclojure.html) [pages](http://www.bagofsouls.com/entry/41/Easily_installing_clojure_and_) that tell me how to set up Clojure, Leiningen and VimClojure, but I can't get any of them to properly start the REPL. There is always an exception raised from a forName() call.

I read this could possibly be due to an incompatibility between VimClojure and Clojure 1.2.

Has anyone gotten this combination to work? Can you post instructions/hints?

Comment: Short answer - switch to emacs (which, I am still trying to).  
I wasted a lot of time trying to get the REPL work using VimClojure.  You can see the related question I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073013/how-do-i-setup-repl-on-vim

Comment: So emacs is the better alternative (when you are still trying)? There is now requirement whatsoever to use the delivered repl with vimclojure. It works also perfectly well with an external one. You just have to start a nailgun server there in a background thread. (In fact the vim repl has some quite significant shortcomings which cannot easily be fixed and are dictated by vim itself)

Answer (score 1):

The latest release 2.1.2 is not compatible with Clojure 1.2 due to some change in the reader. The next release will work with 1.2. There are just a few things left to be ironed out before the release is ready. So stay tuned.

EDIT: There is a [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/vimclojure) where you can get support with VimClojure. Or you may drop me an email directly: my initials at kotka dot de.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, setting up vimclojure can be a pain, but I got it working (for the most part). I documented my steps here: http://greengiraffe.posterous.com/setting-up-vimclojure